# Unit Of Work & Generic Repository with Entity Framework 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 4 with Entity Framework 5. I have model classes and Entity Maps to map existing tables to those model classes. All this is setup fine and works great.

Now I want to mock this. I created Unit Of Work that takes the DataContext and uses a Generic Repository. Upon that I built services to be able to get data from many repositories at once and only needing to have one instance of the DataContext. This also works great.

**Now to the problem:** I want to test the services, with mock data. When I create the Unit Of Work instance, I want to be able to insert a DataContext that is mocked instead of the real DataContext.

I tried to create a IContext interface and let the real and mocked DataContext implement that but ran into problems with DbSet. I tried to use IDbSet and creating a FakeDbSet but without success. I also read on the internet that mocking the context with IDbSet and using a FakeDbSet is a bad approach.

Do you have any idea what would be the best way to achieve this? What I have now is the behavior I would like to keep, but would really like to be able to mock the data from the Model classes in the DataContext.

*I'm aware of that Entity Framework already comes with Unit Of Work behavior and that you don't need to add extra behavior on top of that. But I wanted to wrap that inside of another class that keeps track of all the repositories (called UnitOfWork class).*

**Edit:** I wrote two articles explaining my solution with both LINQ and Entity Framework.

http://gaui.is/how-to-mock-the-datacontext-linq/

http://gaui.is/how-to-mock-the-datacontext-entity-framework/

Here's my code:

**IRepository.cs**

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    void Add(T entity);
    void Delete(T entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    T GetById(long Id);
    IEnumerable<T> All();
    IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
}
```

**IUnitOfWork.cs**

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    void Save();
}
```

**Repository.cs**

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IDbContext _context;
    private readonly IDbSet<T> _dbset;

    public Repository(IDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
        _dbset = context.Set<T>();
    }

    public virtual void Add(T entity)
    {
        _dbset.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(T entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
    }

    public virtual void Update(T entity)
    {
        var entry = _context.Entry(entity);
        _dbset.Attach(entity);
        entry.State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual T GetById(long id)
    {
        return _dbset.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<T> All()
    {
        return _dbset;
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> Find(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
    {
        return _dbset.Where(predicate);
    }
}
```

**UnitOfWork.cs**

```
public class UnitOfWork<TContext> : IUnitOfWork where TContext : IDbContext, new()
{
    private readonly IDbContext _ctx;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> _repositories;
    private bool _disposed;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        _ctx = new TContext();
        _repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
        _disposed = false;
    }

    public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
    {
        if (_repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(TEntity)))
            return _repositories[typeof(TEntity)] as IRepository<TEntity>;

        var repository = new Repository<TEntity>(_ctx);
        _repositories.Add(typeof(TEntity), repository);
        return repository;
    }

    public void Save()
    {
        _ctx.SaveChanges();
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this._disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                _ctx.Dispose();
            }

            this._disposed = true;
        }
    }
}
```

**ExampleService.cs**

```
public class ExampleService
{
    private IRepository<Example> m_repo;

    public ExampleService(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        m_repo = uow.GetRepository<Example>();
    }

    public void Add(Example Example)
    {
        m_repo.Add(Example);
    }

    public IEnumerable<Example> getAll()
    {
        return m_repo.All();
    }
}
```

**ExampleController.cs**

```
public IEnumerable<Example> GetAll()
{
    // Create Unit Of Work object
    IUnitOfWork uow = new UnitOfWork<AppDataContext>();

    // Create Service with Unit Of Work attached to the DataContext
    ExampleService service = new ExampleService(uow);

    return service.getAll();
}
```

Comment: I am also having same problem as you mentioned. However, can you post your code for IDbContext  and concrete class which implements IDbContext? This will help me a lot. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Nexus [http://gaui.is/how-to-mock-the-datacontext-entity-framework/](http://gaui.is/how-to-mock-the-datacontext-entity-framework/)

Comment: @Gaui Wouldn't it be better to create your `UnitOfWork` instance inside your `ExampleService` class instead of your controller? That way your controller doesn't need to know about what `DbContext` it needs, it leaves it to the service.

Comment: @GFoley83 That's just a preference really. If you want to have many services using the same uow object, you would need to do it outside the service.

Comment: I would argue that, if the consumer of your service is remote, that you do not want the uow existing outside the service.  You don't want open transactions/connections hanging around in a stateless environment.  If the consumer is not remote, this may not be an issue.

Comment: Why have you called `SaveChanges` on each operation in `Repository` class?  This will not be transaction safe

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your `ExampleService` class is expecting `IUnitOfWork`, that means you just need another `IUnitOfWork` that is a Mock and its `GetRepository()` method will return an `IRepository` Mock.

For example (not really a Mock but In-Memory stub):

```
  public InMemoryRepository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class
  {
        ........
  }

  public InMemoryUnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
  {
       public IRepository<TEntity> GetRepository<TEntity>() where TEntity : class
       {
            return new InMemoryRepository<TEntity>();
       }
  }
```

Then:

```
public IEnumerable<Example> GetAll()
{
    // Create Unit Of Work object
    IUnitOfWork uow = new InMemoryUnitOfWork();

    // Create Service with Unit Of Work
    ExampleService service = new ExampleService(uow);

    return service.getAll();
}
```

Comment: Excellent, works like a charm! I like this better than creating a fake context with IDbSet and FakeDbSet. That seems so wrong. Thank you very much for this!

Comment: This seems neat and clean way instead of mocking DBSets,  thanks for sharing I was also wandering for the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following link it is very helpful.

[Generic Repository Pattern in MVC3 Application with Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640294/Learning-MVC-Part-6-Generic-Repository-Pattern-in)

[Entity Framework and Data Patterns](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns)