# Repository Pattern in Mvc 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, repository-pattern

I am having a project which is in Mvc 4.0. The project has already included EF in it nad using its classes with database first Approach. I have to do some work in it using repository pattern. I have read many blogs and I am still confused with how to actually integrate the Entity Framework with Repository. From where I have to start. I am reading this [example](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

The explanation is okay but how can I merge the both concepts.What I tried is created a model class as the above link has suggested but in the above link in student class they have taken list of Icollection where enrollment is table in database . I am also passing my table name to list but not working.

Total Process I have done. Please tell me if this right or Wrong
Step1: I created a database named School
Step2 : I added entity framework in the Project.
Step3: I am now creating a model of the same properties as the Student table has.
Step4 : where I am now stucked. How will I create a Icollection??
Please help as soon as it can be possible. I will be thank ful to you.

Comment: [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/572761/Generic-repository-pattern-using-EF-with-Dependenc) is a very informative article on the generic repository pattern that I have implemented in my own projects and that I would recommend.

Comment: Can somebody Please tell me steps that I have to follow for repository pattern in code first approach but have entity framework already in the project. Please, it will help me alot.

Comment: [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2013/10/01/using-the-repository-pattern-in-an-asp-net-mvc-4-0-application.aspx) is a practical tutorial that you can read and implement this pattern in your application

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out this question [Unit Of Work & Generic Repository with Entity Framework 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716527/unit-of-work-generic-repository-with-entity-framework-5) I think it is described well there.

Here is complete package you can use http://www.nuget.org/packages/Repository.EntityFramework/

And one more link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application.

BUT before implementing repository pattern I would suggest you to think "Do you really need it?".

Comment: Strongly agree with @Avenged question, here's article about it: http://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton

Comment: I agree with "do you really need it"? I often use a simple service "layer" for some business logic. Data access can happen through ORM. That said, my apps are usually smaller and limited to less than 100 users at once. Repository pattern may be more useful for larger apps.

Answer (score 5):

If you would like to see a real world scenario of how the Repository is implemented then I suggest you check out some open source projects.

**Nop Commerce**
Uses the repository pattern and dependency injection
http://nopcommerce.codeplex.com/

**Videos**
There is also the ASP.NET video series (free) about building an MVC Storefront
http://www.asp.net/mvc/videos/mvc-1/aspnet-mvc-storefront/aspnet-mvc-storefront-part-2-the-repository-pattern

**Open Access samples**
Telerik has some great examples using their ORM (OpenAccess). Even though it uses a different ORM, the repository pattern is still applicable to EntityFramework.
http://www.telerik.com/products/orm.aspx

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example that you might find useful: [Implementing the Repository and Unit of Work Patterns in an ASP.NET MVC Application, from www.asp.net](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some article which explain basic about Repository Pattern also sample example with source code.

[CRUD Operations Using the Repository Pattern in MVC](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/644605/CRUD-Operations-Using-the-Repository-Pattern-in-MV)

[Repository pattern, done right](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/526874/Repositorypluspattern-2cplusdoneplusright)

[Generic Repository Pattern in MVC3 Application with Entity Framework](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640294/Learning-MVC-Part-6-Generic-Repository-Pattern-in)

Answer (score 1):

```
public class AccountBrandRepository : GenericRepository<AccountBrand>
{   
     TestEntities _context;

     public TestRepository(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork)
         : base(unitOfWork as VoltEntities)
     {
         if (unitOfWork == null)
             throw new ArgumentNullException("unitOfWork");
         _context = unitOfWork as TestEntities;
     }
}
```

Comment: Maybe you could add some context to the answer?