# Entity Framework (v6) closes connections after exception without using statment? Experiment resuls inside

Tags: entity-framework, exception, dispose, using, using-statement

I realy tested this thing for both ADO.net and EF v.6 and watched connections in SQL table

```
select * from sys.dm_exec_connections
```

Methods to be tested looked like this:

1) ADO.net with using

```
  using(var Connection = new SqlConnection(conString))
  {
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Connection))
    {    
       Connection.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQueryReader();
       throw new Exception()  // Connections were closed after unit-test had been 
       //finished.  Expected behaviour
     }
  }
```

2) ADO.net withour using

```
var Connection = new SqlConnection(conString);
using (var command = new SqlCommand(queryString, Connection))
{
    Connection.Open();
     command.ExecuteNonQueryReader();
    throw new Exception() // Connections were NOT closed after unit-test had been finished

     finished.  I closed them manually via SQL.  Expected behaviour
    }
```

1) EF with using.

```
 using (var ctx = new TestDBContext())
    {
        ctx.Items.Add(item);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
        throw new Exception() // Connections were closed, as expected.

     }
```

2) EF without using

```
 var ctx = new TestDBContext();             
 ctx.Items.Add(item);
 ctx.SaveChanges();
 throw new Exception() // Connections WERE successfully closed, as NOT expected.
```

I don't know why is it so, but EF automatically closed connections. Also All the patterns of [repository](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and [UnitOfWork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16716527/unit-of-work-generic-repository-with-entity-framework-5) which use EF don't use using statement. It's  very strange for me, because DBContext is Disposable type, but it's a fact.

1. The quesion is why is it so: why EF automatically releases the
   resource (connection) after exception? Maybe in Microsoft they did
   something new for handling excpetions and close connections better
   than in pure ADO.net?
2. Why all the exmaples of patterns ignore using statment?

**ADDED:**
*>> For your last example, the connection is open and closed in your third line of code*

Connections are created in Connection Pool just when you try to get to cxt.Items DbSet, not before and not after:
[image]
By moment of callsing Save connections already exist:
[image]
[image]
also they existing and after leaving Save and after throwing the exception and test-method has been left:
[image]
and are closed after the program stopped working:
[image]

Comment: For your last example, the connection is open and closed in your third line of code. Same for EF 5.
This is not because of ADO.NET, this is EF design.
You can stop the debugger in your Exception line and before you step over you can see that the connection has been closed when it returned from `SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DbContext` does not open the connection when you initialize it.
`DbContext` opens and closes the connection for every operation you execute eg. any query or a call to `SaveChanges`.

If you want to control when the connection is open or closed you will have to pass your own connection and specify that the context **does not** own  this connection by using the overloaded constructor: `public DbContext(DbConnection existingConnection, bool contextOwnsConnection)`

And to answer your question, YES, you still need to use a **`using`** block or call Dispose to free any unmanaged resource. Remember that EF uses ADO.NET and this one invokes many unmanaged APIs under the hood.

hope this helps

**UPDATE:**
In order to verify all this create/add a new constructor for your context:

```
public class TestDbContext : DbContext
{
  public TestDbContext(DbConnection connection, bool contextOwnsConnection)
    : base(connection, contextOwnsConnection) { }
}
```

Then use the same code you used in your example when calling `SaveChanges()`

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here");
using (var ctx = new TestDbContext(conn, [false/true])) //play with true and false
{
  conn.Open(); //you can also comment this to discover other situations
  ctx.Items.Add(item);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  throw new Exception(); //also comment this line and you will see the connection
                         //is still open because it is not controlled inside the 
                         //DbContext
}
```

If you use `true` for the second parameter in your context constructor you will notice that the connection is gone when your test finishes. This is the default behavior for a DbContext because the connection is created within and the context owns the connection (opens and closes as needed).

On the other hand if you use `false` you will notice the connection is still open even when the context is disposed if the connection is opened by calling `conn.Open()`. If the context calls `conn.Open()` internally to execute any query or save changes the context will control when to open and close the connection.

You can play with the second Boolean parameter and the call to `conn.Open()` to discover very interesting different scenarios.

The following example shows you that even when you created the connection manually, but since you didn't open it manually, the context will open and close automatically. The managed connection state is closed even before the exception is thrown and your native connection is still open.

```
var conn = new SqlConnection("your connection string here");
using (var ctx = new TestDbContext(conn, false)) 
{
  //conn.Open();
  ctx.Items.Add(item);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  var state = conn.State
  throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't understand you are talking about or your answered another question. There is no need to know who owns the connection. There is a scenes to know are there any resource leaks and not closed connections or not. And for ADO the leak exists and for EF not.

Comment: the last part ("to use a using block or call Dispose  to free any unmanaged resources") was just refuted by experiment.  That's why I ask about such behaviour.

Comment: @Artem - The behavior you expose has been the same behavior in prior versions of EF.

Comment: maybe. I just specified version. The quesion is why is it so: why EF automatically releases the resource (connection) after exception?

Comment: It is not after the exception. It is right before returns from `SaveChanges()`. This is what I was explaining in the first 2 paragraphs of my answer.

Comment: Thanks, but please, watch the added pictures to get know when connections really exist

Comment: I guess you need to understand how SQL Native Client connection pools work, and how they are completely different thing to .NET `SqlConnection`. What is actually happening is that inside `SaveChanges()` you will find `SqlConnection.Open()` and `SqlConnection.Close()` just like in your first example. This will realease any unmanaged resource so that the *sleeping* native connection can be closed after you close your application.
Native connection can remain open for longer so that multiple .NET connections actually use the same native connection.

Comment: So, how can I reproduce the exception inside SaveChanges?

Comment: No, you can't because the call to save changes in  DbContext is controlled by EF, but check my UPDATE to get the open connection at the end of your text when using `false` as the second parameter.

Comment: sorry, I meant "at the end of your **test**"